# Change direction of code element in a div

Tags: html, css

I wanna to have `code` with `direction:ltr` that it's in a div with `direction:rtl`. Here is my Example:

```css
div{direction:rtl !important;}
code{direction:ltr; background-color:#eee;padding:2px 5px;}
```

```html
<div>
    سلام این یک <code>var a = 1;</code> کد است.
<div>
```

As you can see the semicolon is not in the right situation.How can I Fix this issue css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to add `unicode-bidi: bidi-override` to the `code` tag. You can read more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/

```css
div {
  direction: rtl !important;
}

code {
  direction: ltr;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  سلام این یک <code>var a = 1;</code> کد است.
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just insert `display: inline-block;` to code selector.

```
code {
   display: inline-block;
   //other css...
}
```

```css
div{direction:rtl !important;}
code{direction:ltr; background-color:#eee;padding:2px 5px;display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div>
    سلام این یک <code>var a = 1;</code> کد است.
<div>
```